# Passing parameter value through a function from anchor tag in a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, parameter-passing

I have a `GridView`, within which I have an anchor tag. In the anchor's `onclick` I am calling a function and passing some parameters. I am getting an error "server tag is not well formed".

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1">

 <asp:TemplateField>

 <ItemTemplate>

 <div id="div1" runat="server" >

  <a onclick="rateDocument('<%#Eval("FileRef")%>','<%#Eval("ListId")%>',<%#Eval("ID")%>,2)" class="">    

  </a>

 </div>

 </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

</asp:GridView>


function rateDocument(documentWebURL,rtListId, rtItemId, currentRating) 
{

}
```

However,If the values are hard-coded (as below) then it works without error.

```
<a runat="server" onclick="rateDocument('sites/SI/IBX/','{A1AF-12FA92C6F8CD}',113,1)" class="">
```

Comment: Try putting the single quotes around your server tags (Eval), that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"` for `onclick` with `'` like

```
<a onclick='rateDocument(<%#Eval("FileRef")%>,<%#Eval("ListId")%>,<%#Eval("ID")%>,2);' class="">    
  </a>
```

Comment: Try adding `href=""`.

Comment: Try this solution 

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/523909/Theplusserverplustagplusisplusnotpluswellplusforme

Comment: cant use link button ...only use anchor tag

Comment: Use the anchor tag but attributes and the procedure to set `onclick`, you can take it from there. You can try this solution also.